# How to specify K cluster in Hierarchical clustering with noisy data?

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering, noise, dendrogram

I'm new in Mining and Clustering and I wonder how to cut off the hierarchical clustering *Dendrogram* to obtain a specific number of clusters. The problem is here that the data is noisy and the `SLINK` algorithm consider these noises as a cluster and when I cut off the *Dendrogram* to obtain exactly ***K*** cluster, it gives me some noisy cluster and so ignores all or some of ***K*** expected clusters. So I think there should be some techniques to cut the *Dendrogram* without considering the noisy clusters.

**Note** that I know the number of ***K*** and it's not a problem how to specify this number!

Thanks.

Comment: How can noise be a cluster?  If it is random, then it will scatter things randomly. If it isn't random then, is it noise? 

Seems to me that your noisy cluster is actually something interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the height h such that there are k non-trivial (non noise) clusters.

Then cut the tree at this height.

Note that this may not be satisfiable. If your data is a single gaussian, it may not be possible to find k non-trivial clusters.